# How do I resolve these error messages?

Tags: mount, fstab, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image]

```
Processing fstab with mount -a failed.
Failed to mount C:\, see dmesg for more details.
Failed to mount D:\, see dmesg for more details.

<3>WSL (9) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:370: getpwuid(1000) failed 2
<3>WSL (9) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:374: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (9) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:577: execvpe /bin/sh failed 2
<3>WSL (9) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:586: Create process not expected to return
Processing fstab with mount -a failed.
Failed to mount C:\, see dmesg for more details.
Failed to mount D:\, see dmesg for more details.

<3>WSL (7) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:370: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (7) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:374: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (7) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:577: execvpe /bin/sh failed 2
<3>WSL (7) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:586: Create process not expected to return
Processing fstab with mount -a failed.
Failed to mount C:\, see dmesg for more details.
Failed to mount D:\, see dmesg for more details.

<3>WSL (7) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:370: getpwuid(1000) failed 2
<3>WSL (7) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:374: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (7) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:577: execvpe /bin/sh failed 2
<3>WSL (7) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:586: Create process not expected to return

[process exited with code 1 (0x00000001)]][1]
```

How can I resolve this issue to use Ubuntu?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Does the problem occur (a) in a fresh installation of Ubuntu in WSL or (b) did the virtual Ubuntu system work before? In case (a) add details how exactly you installed this and/or what instructions you followed. In case (b) tell us what you changed before the problem occurred.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue?  I haven't seen any replies to @Bodo's questions, and this would certainly be useful information.  The `execvpe /bin/sh` part of it indicates that the filesystem may be corrupted in some way, either a missing `/bin/` directory, deleted symlink, or for some other reason.  Do you get the same message if you `wsl ~ -e /usr/bin/sh`?  Come to think of it, it would normally be trying `/usr/bin/bash`, so the fact that it's trying for `sh` may even mean that it can't access `/etc/passwd`.